# Error Class c++ Class. Don't know what is it

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
    Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall BullsAndCows::BullsAndCows(void)" (??0BullsAndCows@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
```

Got this error but I am not sure what is it talking about and also I got that problem that says is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Its in c++.

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://www.sscce.org/) for guidance. "

Comment: Post the code in your .cpp file that contains the `int main()` function.

Comment: You must provide some of your code - at least main function and implementation of BullsAndCows class, otherwise you might not get a complete answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Linker can not find the symbol `BullsAndCows::BullsAndCows()`.
Meaning that you declared the `BullsAndCows` constructor , but forgot to implement it.

Comment: and if you do not declare any constructor and you need it, the compiler will implicitly generate a default constructor.